# error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino

Please bear with me, I'm new at C and I'm trying to program an Arduino. I want to write a program that spits out a data frame of specific length with byte values ranging from 0-255. The minimum code to reproduce the error is in the code block below. When compiling I receive the following error:

> ```
> sketch_apr09b.cpp: In function ‘char assembleFrame()’:
> sketch_apr09b.cpp:9:10: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’
> ```

Now my impression is that I'm mistreating the 'return frame', but I just can't figure out what's wrong.

```
char assembleFrame() {
  char frame[] = { 
    0x61 , 0x62 , 0x63
  };
  return frame;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin( 115200 );
};

void loop() {
  char frame = assembleFrame();
  Serial.print( frame );
}
```

When I run a hexdump on the receiving PC, I want to see:

```
00000000  61 62 63                                          |abc|
00000003
```

I've found a lot of similar questions, wasn't able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**:
This is what I came up with so far, but receiving wrong data. I think I'm sending the pointer to the actual data with this.

```
byte *assembleFrame() {
  byte frame[] = { 4 , 'a' , 'b' , 'c' };
  return frame;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin( 115200 );
};

void loop() {
  byte *frame = assembleFrame();
  Serial.write( frame , frame[ 0 ] );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `char` type is used to store a single `char` (a byte).

Your function definition `char assembleFrame` specifies the function will only be returning a single `char`, so when you try to return a `char[]` / `char *` (`char` array/pointer), it fails.

Looks like `Serial.print()` can handle a `char *`, which will potentially need to be null-terminated (because it asks for no length specifier).

```
char *assembleFrame() {
  char frame[] = {
    0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x00 // null byte to signify end of string
  };
  return frame;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin( 115200 );
};

void loop() {
  char *frame = assembleFrame();
  Serial.print( frame );
}
```

Comment: This code compiles, and I see what I was doing wrong, thnx. I was typing `char* assembleFrame()` instead of `char *assembleFrame()`. But I have a new problem now: I can't use null-terminated strings, because the payload may contain null bytes. Fixed size is no problem. Is that easy to solve? (commenting your reply I haven't had a chance to DuckDuckGo this, but going to do it right now).

Comment: You can send bytes to `Serial.write()` one at a time, which should allow nulls. Maybe have `assembleFrame` write the frame to a buffer (pointer to a string), and return a length - then you can iterate through the buffer and `Serial.write()` each `char`.

Comment: yes, found it just 1 second ago myself :) actually you can pass a length parameter with Serial.write( buf , len 0)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this code:

```
char frame = assembleFrame();
```

Given how you're using it later, clearly `frame` needs to be declared `char *` not `char`, and `assembleFrame` needs to be declared as returning `char *`.

Answer (score -1):

`assembleFrame` returns `char` while you return `char*`. As I don't know what are you doing, I cannot suggest how to fix that. Maybe fixing the return type is the proper way.